# При запуске программы на C# ошибки отображается в виде вопросов

Tags: c#

Я установил VS Code и добавил .NET SDK дабы запускать программу на C#. Написал простенький код, запускаю и получаю ошибку в виде знак вопросов, не знаю что делать, подскажите, что это может значить и как это решить?

Сам код:

```
namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Hello {         
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Привет, мир!");
        }
    }
}
```

Сама ошибка:

`?? ??????? ????? ??????????? ??????. ????????? ? ???, ??? ?????? ?????????? ? C:\User\Test, ??? ????????? ???? ? ??????? ? ??????? --project.`

Возможно, я бы решил эту проблему если бы его понимал

Comment: к сожалению, не могу подсказать, как исправить ошибку, но советую пользоваться Visual Studio, а не Visual Studio Code для разработки на C#

Comment: @iKuzmychov дело может быть совершенно не в VS Code

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, как вы компилируете этот код и запускаете его. Иначе мы можем только гадать

Comment: Шрифты русские поставьте в VS Code. У вас ANSI кодировка вывода, а надо либо CP866 либо UTF-8, и соответствубщий шрифт. Знаки вопроса - русские буквы.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko Запускал через терминал. Я решил свою проблему, сменив язык VS на английский

Comment: @aepot Пытался, но проблема так и оставалась